# Custom alert using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I create a custom alert function in Javascript?

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive?

Comment: I want to change the default title from 'The page at http//...' to my own custom title. Is that possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can override the existing `alert` function, which exists on the `window` object:

```
window.alert = function (message) {
  // Do something with message
};
```

Answer (score 17):

This is the solution I came up with. I wrote a generic function to create a jQueryUI dialog. If you wanted, you could override the default alert function using Matt's suggestion: window.alert = alert2;

```
// Generic self-contained jQueryUI alternative to
// the browser's default JavaScript alert method.
// The only prerequisite is to include jQuery & jQueryUI
// This method automatically creates/destroys the container div
// params:
//     message = message to display
//     title = the title to display on the alert
//     buttonText = the text to display on the button which closes the alert
function alert2(message, title, buttonText) {

    buttonText = (buttonText == undefined) ? "Ok" : buttonText;
    title = (title == undefined) ? "The page says:" : title;

    var div = $('<div>');
    div.html(message);
    div.attr('title', title);
    div.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: [{
            text: buttonText,
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                div.remove();
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Technically you can change what the alert function does. But, you cannot change the title or other behavior of the modal window launched by the native alert function (besides the text/content).

Comment: Alright, that's what I needed to know. +1. But accepted advait's answer because he gave me an alternate solution.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for a javascript/html/css replacement, I recommend checking out [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) and its implementation of [modal dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal).

Answer (score 0):

"override" way is not good enough, suggest you to create a custom popup box. The best benefit of this solution is that you can control every details.

Comment: [Simple Popup](https://github.com/dabeng/Simple-Popup) is another lightweight alternative for you.

Comment: I recommend just editing your answer to include these links.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not using the default alert.
Not even formating.
But, I recomend you using [Sweet alert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to do that.