# How to increase font size in javascript alert()

Tags: javascript

Can I control the font size of the string in a javascript `alert()` call??!

I've the image below and I want to increase the font size so that it is legible.

[Javascript Alert Pop Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYTBP.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom alert using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391864/custom-alert-using-javascript)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can I control the font size of the string in a javascript alert() call??!

Nope. How the alert window is rendered is entirely up to the browser.

You would have to use a JavaScript based dialog windows alternative like [jQuery UI Dialog.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is controlled by the browser. I don't use alerts anymore I use [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), it's fully customizable

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is not possible.

However, you have a several choices:

If you want to create it yourself as a totally custom thing, create a new div element in your DOM (as the last child of the body, and give it the maximum z-index you can or you use), position that absolute (top:0,left:0), and write there HTML whatever you want. With some JS you can positon it to center of the screen/layout. :)

Or use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)... :)