# How to change font style in alertbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the designing purpose,how to change font color and style in alertbox. Actually i have use session in my project and if user do not respond till 30 seconds, i am trying to warn user using alertbox, or anyother way to do this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you showing the alert?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase font size in javascript alert()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507823/how-to-increase-font-size-in-javascript-alert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a console.log( $(this) ) instead of alert

Then add CSS like

```
$(this).css('font-size','12px');
```

Answer (score 0):

`alertbox` is built-in, so, we can't edit it. You can create dialogs and can style them as you want.