# Changing font size of alert dialog with respect to screen sizes

Tags: javascript, alert, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a alert dialog which is displayed on pressing a button. But the font of the alert dialog is okay for small screens but for large screens like 10 or 7 inch tablet, the font is too small. In order to change the size of normal text view, I have used dimens. How can I solve this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: Just a regular `alert("Hello");` style box? If this is case, I don't believe it is possible to change the font size.

Comment: Regular alert dialog where there is a one line title followed by a list of options which can selected.

Comment: if they are standard javascript methods (alert/confirm/prompt) then you cannot change the font style. What you can do is use a custom dialog that will be managed by yourself. This can be a jquery dialog, for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507823/how-to-increase-font-size-in-javascript-alert)