# How to make kendo window to behave like alert?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm tyring to catch the page leave event & check if the user have any unsaved changes. When I'm trying with alert, its working fine, the page reloading/leaving after I press the ok button on alert box as expected. But I'm trying to use kendo window for the confirmation with yes, no & cancel button. The problem is kendo window can't prevent the page from leaving or reloading, it just pops up & the page leaves almost immediately, leaving the user no time to respond to the window. I would like to stop the page from leaving until I press a button on kendo window.

Here is my code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

            if (changeStatus == 1)
            {
              //e.preventDefault();
              saveChangeWindow.open();
              //alert("test");
            }
        };
```

if I place the e.preventDefault(), then the page is waiting but an default message showing, which I don't actually need. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you cant - showing a Window and waiting for the user to select a button is an async operation in contrast to the **confirm** or **alert** functions of the window.

Comment: if so, can I customise the confirm or alert to meet my requirement of having three different buttons?

Comment: I am afraid you can't. Here is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/3391974/332124